# How to disable logging Neo4j queries in Hibernate OGM?

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, neo4j, hibernate-ogm

I'm using Hibernate OGM with Neo4j database.

For every operation, like creating new entity, there are many log entries with Cypher queries produced:

```
...
2015-02-27 11:09:41.825+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: CREATE (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.869+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: CREATE (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.873+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: MATCH (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.908+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: MATCH (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.911+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: CREATE (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.913+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: MATCH (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
2015-02-27 11:09:41.914+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: MATCH (n:ENTITY:TreeElement {id: {0}}) RETURN n
...
```

How to disable this?

I've tried setting `hibernate.show_sql` property in persistance.xml file:

```
   <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "false" />
```

, but with no result.

Comment: This needs to be fixed with OGM-755 as described in Davide's answer. Let me only add that `hibernate.show_sql` is not honored by Hibernate OGM (after all, Hibernate OGM does not deal with SQL). We look into providing a similar mechanism for OGM with [OGM-728](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-728).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to disable it. I 've created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-755 to keep track of the issue.